EWMA formula for SGD with momentum different than generic EWMA formula
I am currently trying to understand how SGD with momentum works, what I understand is it uses the Exponential Weighted Moving Average concept to make the updates smoother. We take weighted average of the gradients using the below formula
v t = β⋅v t−1 + (1−β)⋅∇J(θ t)
However, in general EWMA is also used when we have time series data, there we use it calculate EWMA of time series data points but the formula is a bit different as shown below
EMA t = α⋅X t + (1−α)⋅EMA t−1
As you could notice, in the 1st formula we try to smoothen the gradients and the gradient part in the formula is multiplied to (1-β), whereas in the second part we smoothen the data point X t and that is multiplied to β.
Why is the formula different in the above two cases.

The formula is the same in the two cases; just swap $\beta$ and $1-\beta$, which is a meaningless thing to do, mathematically speaking.  Also, please format your math with Mathjax!
